# the use of destination in spring cloud stream , with rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I use rabbitmq as the middleware in cloud stream ,when I configure the application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        usertest:       #channelName 
          content-type: application/json
          group: testGroup
          destination: topic888 #destination，
          binder: rabbit1
```

I can't understand the key meaning of destination.
official definition is :

> **destination**
>
> The target destination of a channel on the bound middleware (e.g., the RabbitMQ exchange or Kafka topic). If the channel is bound as a consumer, it could be bound to multiple destinations and the destination names can be specified as comma separated String values. If not set, the channel name is used instead.

Also,I found when consumer and producer have different destinations , It did't stop consumer from consuming.

Answer (score 1):

The `destination` depends on the binder type. For kafka, it's the topic; for RabbitMQ, it's an exchange.

The producer publishes to the exchange.

The consumer binds a queue to the exchange. Anonymous consumers bind a temporary, auto-delete queue, consumers with a `group` bind a queue called `topic888.testGroup` in your case (`destination.group`).

> Also,I found when consumer and producer have different destinations , It did't stop consumer from consuming.

I don't see how that's possible, with the binder doing the provisioning, for the reasons discussed above.

It's possible if you manually bind a queue with the correct name to a different exchange that the producer is publishing to.

Comment: So, that means each channel in consumer side will have different queues in rabbitmq, because I found that destination is an exchange and group is a queue that will bind to the destination, isn't it?

Comment: On the consumer side, the destination is a combination of exchange and queue; if there is a `group` property, the queue is a permanent queue with name `dest.group`; if there is no group, the queue has a randomized name and is auto-delete (it is deleted when the consumer stops).

Comment: Gary, is there a way to avoid `destination.` from the queue name in case of RabbitMQ? I don't see why I should repeat the Exchange in the queue name.

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers; it won't help the community find questions/answers. Ask a new question instead. See [the documentation for consumer properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties). Specifically `queueNameGroupOnly` - "When true, consume from a queue with a name equal to the group. Otherwise the queue name is `destination.group`. This is useful, for example, when using Spring Cloud Stream to consume from an existing RabbitMQ queue."